# Change cell value of DataGrid based on column data type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am using WPF `DataGrid` to display a `DataTable`.
I am using `AutoGenerateColumns = True`  to auto-generate the columns as the `DataTable` is set dynamically.

I need to change the cell value(s) of a column if it is of a particular data type. 
For example if the Column datatype is `DateTime`, then I need to display some `string` in its place.

I checked [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). How would I attach such a converter to DataGrid columns which are generated dynamically ?

Comment: _then I need to display some string in its place_ A string such as the formatted date? Or a string like "I'm Replaced"?

Comment: @Jim, I took DateTime and string datatype as an example, it could be anything, I just need to attach the Value Converters on columns that will be generated dynamically(auto-generated).

Answer (score 4):

Use the event `AutoGeneratingColumn` and attach a converter to the column's binding.

**Event**

```
    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
        {
            var column = (DataGridTextColumn)e.Column;
            var dateTimeConverter = new DateTimeConverter();
            ((Binding)column.Binding).Converter = dateTimeConverter;
        }
    }
```

**Converter**

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "Override This";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Results in any column that's bound to a `DateTime` property to display "Override This" as its text